# Pointing to static arrays, but dereferencing without the use of *

Tags: c++

I have a series of NX objects (e.g., a static bool array of dimension [NX][N1][N2] in the example below).

I would like to loop over these objects. At each iteration, an object called 'A' is to function as a surrogate for the corresponding element 'B[x]' in the series.
However, the code inside the loop is legacy code, so we cannot really change how we refer to 'A' itself

```
    const int NX = ...;
    const int N1 = ...;
    const int N2 = ...;
    bool B[NX][N1][N2];

    Code_needed: declare A here (maybe first defining a class template?)

    int main(){

      for(int x = 0; x < NX; ++x){
        Code_needed: make A refer to B[x] here (maybe A = &B[x])
        // In the following, "A[i][j]" should refer to B[x][i][j]...
        A[3][5] = true; // This is legacy code, so we cannot change it
                        // (e.g., cannot add a * in front of A)
      }        
    }
```

Note that the types of objects on which I want to apply this are heavy, such as arrays of containers, so copying them over inside the loop is not acceptable.  Maximizing performance is generally of interest in this application.

Would appreciate the help!!

EDIT: How would the answer be affected, if `A` were to be a scalar (i.e., it is `B[NX]` only)?

Comment: What do you mean by legacy code? It's precompiled and you don't have the source, or what?

Comment: I have the source but it is big and I would prefer not have to go update all that (also keep in mind that I have multiple A's for which this would need to be done....

Comment: What is wrong with just doing bool **A=B[x]?

Comment: @Jack: You mean apart from the fact that it doesn't work? :) There is no conversion from a two-dimensional array to a nested pointer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define a reference to a two-dimensional array inside the for loop:

```
bool (&A)[N1][N2] = B[x];
```

Now `A[i][j]` is equivalent to `B[x][i][j]`.

Note that you cannot move the definition of `A` outside the for loop, because references have to be initialized when they are defined, and they cannot be rebound later.

If you need to define `A` outside the for loop and reassign inside the for loop, use a pointer instead:

```
// outside the for loop
bool (*A)[N2];

// inside the for loop
A = B[x];
```

---

And here is a complete code example which compiles just fine on my compiler:

```
const int NX = 3;
const int N1 = 5;
const int N2 = 7;

bool B[NX][N1][N2];
bool (*A)[N2];

int main()
{
    for (int x = 0; x < NX; ++x)
    {
        A = B[x];
        A[3][5] = true;
    }
}
```

---

You can also write an alias class template which overloads the assignment operator appropriately:

```
template <typename T>
class alias
{
    T* p;

    alias(const alias&);
    alias& operator=(const alias&);

public:

    alias() : p(0) {}

    void rebind(T& x)
    {
        this->p = &x;
    }

    void operator=(const T& x)
    {
        *p = x;
    }

    operator T&()
    {
        return *p;
    }
};
```

This works with arrays:

```
bool B[NX][N1][N2];
alias<bool[N1][N2]> A;
// ...
A.rebind(B[x]);
A[3][5] = true;
```

And plain bools:

```
bool B[NX];
alias<bool> A;
// ...
A.rebind(B[x]);
A = true;
```

Comment: what if A was an external variable?

Comment: cannot convert `bool [51][51]` to `bool (*)[51][51]` in assignment

Comment: I had originally written `A = &B[x]`, but that would require to add a `*` in front of `A[i][j]`

Comment: @Chrys: The code I posted works fine, I just tested it. Did you solve the problem?

Comment: @Chrys: You must have made an error during copy and paste, the code works fine. See my updated answer for a complete code example. Please let me know if this works for you.

Comment: @Chrys: My best guess is that you wrote `bool (*A)[N1][N2]` instead of `bool (*A)[N2]`.

Comment: Aha!.....originally thought that you had inadvertently omited `[N1]`...working with a 2-d (instead of 3-d) array.....I get it now....THANK YOU VERY MUCH!

Comment: quick follow-up....how could I achieve this relatiosnhip-by-reference if A were to be scalar (i.e., array B is `B[NX]` only)?....remember that A needs to be declared once at global scope

Comment: @Fred: Indeed, "bool" was just a proxy for "Class_Containing_Many_Large_Members_With_Expensive_Assignment_Operators"....plus I would also require `B[x] = A` at the end of the loop....in any case, thanks again!

Comment: ok....this is certainly towards the right direction (i always had a feeling that it would involve templates, but my coding abilities are very limited)....  the following problem arises now:  suppose instead of `bool` you have a standard container `vector<int>`....the `alias` class does not support its methods, e.g., `class alias<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >’ has no member named ‘begin’`

Comment: UPDATE: If I change the first line of the template declaration into `template <typename T> class alias : public T` (i.e., inherit from class T), then it seems to compile for standard containers (but not for POD). So, one approach would be to have two alias classes, one for POD (without the `: public T` part) and one for general classes....unless there is a way to merge maybe???

Comment: @Chrys: This is getting way too complex. Honestly, I would just `#define A (B[x])` and be done with it. Or rewrite the code to get rid of the need for aliasing.

Comment: @Fred: Thank you very much for all your help.  I will certainly look into alleviating the need for aliasing at some point in the future, as this whole thing seems to be an artificial issue I have dragged myself into with a lot of "constraints" on how it should be implemented....The `#define` solution is a little bit more complex...the "legacy code" needs to know `x` itself, which needs either be passed all over the place, or become a global variable as well (which is not a good solution, for reasons beyond the scope of this discussion).

Comment: @Fred: `(contd)`:  In any case, your solution works like a charm (i.e., `A` is initialized to `B[x]` and, in the end of the loop, `B[x]` contains the final value of `A`) for 99% of the cases I need it for, basically everything involving POD types.  There are still some issues with getting it to work for vectors of custom class objects....